# Tensorflow and openSUSE

Tags: linux, machine-learning, tensorflow, opensuse

I am interested in installing Tensorflow GPU-enabled in openSUSE but from Tensorflow's site the installation is provided only for Ubuntu. How can I do this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's almost no different between installing on Ubuntu or OpenSUSE.

Follow the instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingVirtualenv).

Note that in step 1, use your own package manager of OpenSUSE instead of `apt-get` which belongs to Ubuntu.